# $\overline{h(X)}$, the closure of $h(X)$ in $Y$ is a variety whose coordinate ring is isomorphic to $A(Y)/\mathrm{rad}(I)$, where $I=\ker(h^*)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Show that if $h:X\to Y$ a variety morphism, then $\overline{h(X)}$, the closure of $h(X)$ in $Y$; it is a variety whose coordinate ring is isomorphic to $A(Y)/\mathrm{rad}(I)$, where $I=\ker(h^*)$**

In this case $h^*:A(Y)\to A(X)$ represents the homomorphism induced by $h:X\to Y$.

I do not know where to start and would appreciate any suggestions that lead me to solve the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: You mean for affine varieties the coordinate ring of the affine subvariety $\overline{h(X)}=V(I)$ is $A(Y)/I$ where $I = \ker(h^* : A(Y) \to Frac(A(X)))$.

Comment: @reuns 
What you say is a question or a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be the ideal of the closure of $h(X)$. Try to prove directly that the kernel of $h^*$ is exactly $I$, by showing that any element in the kernel vanishes on $h(X)$.

Comment: I guess the OP needs a whole definition of what is $X,Y$ their coordinate ring and $h$. And $rad(I)$ appears in the morphisms of schemes ?

Comment: I've assumed that the OP was talking about affine varieties, as you've already commented. If we deal with a morphism of schemes, then we have a quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ given as the kernel of the map $f^{\#} \colon \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ (you need some assumptions on $f$ such that $f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ to be quasi-coherent}.